# Need to make a non blocking / asynchronous method call from my application

Tags: java, oracle, asynchronous, weblogic, method-invocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an make a web request in an async manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542763/how-to-make-an-make-a-web-request-in-an-async-manner)

I need to make a non blocking asynchronous method call from my application.

There is an http url which i need to call but in asynchronous way.

example:

```
URL myPage = new URL("http://www.mypage.com/");
URLConnection yc = myPage.openConnection();
```

but the method to be invoked in non blocking or asynchronous way, so that the thread doesn't get stuck when the server of the target url ( http://www.mypage.com) is not working.

Using Oracle Weblogic Server 10.3.2

Answer (score 3):

You could do it manually by spawning additional thread, or you could use ready-made library that will to the job for you. Have a look at Apache [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)+[HttpAsyncClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/) and [these](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/examples.html) examples